# adding a background image to a Drupal site

Tags: theming

I have a high-resolution white-paper texture background that I want to add to my Drupal site with the default Bartik theme.

I've looked at several posts across the web on how to do this with no clear answer.

I also haven't been able to find a Drupal module to do this. Most of the advice I've read is to modify the theme's CSS files.

But it's not clear which CSS file I should edit.  Colors.css, style.css?

I'm almost certain that the line I need to add is

> ```
>  background-image: url("/images/papertexture.jpg").
> ```

But I'm not sure where to add the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [background image](https://drupal.org/project/bg_image) module

> This is an api module that provides tools to add background images to
>   html elements using the css "background" property. A basic settings
>   page is supplied as well as functions to easily add the "background"
>   property to the page.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on the Drupal Module.
I just installed it and tried playing with it. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to use it
On the Drupal configuration screen, there is a settings page for this module, but it doesnt have a place for me to add my image.
 The top settings is confusion. For Node Settings: Not sure what Node Type I need to select and under
  Node Field, it states "No media or image fields attached to this node type"
And with no documentation, I'm not sure what other steps need to be performed to get this to work.